# jQuery Cycle: Custom Pagination with Previous & Next Buttons

Tags: jquery, pagination, cycle, pager

I have a slideshow that requires custom markup for the pagination, which also includes previous & next buttons. I'm using [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), but I'm having trouble working with both a custom pager and previous & next buttons.

This is what I want the end result of my pager to look like:

```
<ul class="pager">
<li class="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
<li class="one"><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="two"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="three"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="four"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's what my jQuery Cycle code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slides').cycle({
    prev: '.prev',
    next: '.next',
    pager:  '.pager',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '.pager li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
    } 
});
});
```

The problem with this is that it treats the ".previous" list item as the first slide in the pager. How do I offset the pager so it ignores the previous and next items?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take out those li's if you want to use them as prev/next links. You can then stylize the prev/next links using css and place them wherever you need. Try this

Markup

```
<ul class="pager">
<li class="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
<li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="slides">
<li class="one"><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="two"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="three"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="four"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slides').cycle({
    prev: '.prev',
    next: '.next',
    pager:  '.pager',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '.pager li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: Yea, obviously that's not ideal but I guess I don't have another choice without busting out some custom JS magic.